# ExtJs 3.0 : Populate combobox from PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, extjs

In my J2EE web application, i am using ExtJs 3.0. In my form panel I have an combobox.

```
{
        xtype : 'combo',
        name : 'include_type',
        fieldLabel : 'Delivery Vehicle',
        emptyText : 'Delivery Vehicle',
        editable : false,
        hideLabel : true,
        style : 'marginleft:10px',
        /*displayField : 'vname',
        valueField : 'vid',*/
        store : vehicleStore,
        flex : 1
    }
```

An also I am using Postgres and there is a table called **hoobtVehicles**. I need to populate my combobox from this table. I know I have to use JsonReader. But I don't have an any idea how to do this because i am very new to J2EE and ExtJs.

I would be much obliged if anyone please be so kind enough to explain how to do such a thing.

Comment: "Java EE" not "J2EE" these days. What exactly are you using, other than ExtJS? In particular, since this is tagged `postgresql`, what database access tools are in use?

Comment: I have to use jsp & servlets

Answer (score 1):

To talk to the database you need to use appropriate interface technologies.

### Communicating with the database

The [Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html) spec incorporates [JPA 2 (the Java Persistence API)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html), which it tends to push as the main database interface technology. JPA works for simpler applications, but tends to become a performance nightmare for bigger ones with more complex needs due to its [lack of fine grained per-operation fetch control](http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/06/mail-to-jpa-21-expert-group-re-fetch.html).

JPA 2 is a layer on top of ORM tools like Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA, etc, that wraps them up in a standardized and simplified API. If you aren't chasing the painful myth of cross-container portability you can just pick one and use it directly, saving yourself a great deal of suffering.

ORMs like Hiberate are in turn layers on JDBC, Java's low-level database access API. This is implemented for PostgreSQL by the PgJDBC driver. You can, and sometimes should, just use JDBC directly, or use a non-ORM helper layer like MyBatis, Spring JDBC Templates, etc.

If you're totally new to database programming and you're starting in a web based environment, I'd probably start with JPA (if you don't need performance) or one of the ORMs like Hibernate directly.

### Getting and managing database connections

You also have a choice about how you establish a database connection:

- Connect directly in the application with no pooling, etc. This is easy, but it's slow and tends to create performance issues on the database server so it isn't a good idea. You usually bundle the JDBC driver in the app for this configuration.
- Use an in-application connection pool, usually integrated via tools like EclipseLink rather than used directly. You may use the JDBC driver's `java.sql.Driver` directly this way, or might use a `javax.sql.DataSource`. You often bundle the JDBC driver(s) in the app for this configuration.
- Use the container / application server to pool connections and hand them to your application. This requires that you configure connection settings in the *container* not the application, but can work very well. This involves using JNDI to look up a `javax.sql.DataSource` provided by the JDBC driver, but it's usually done (again) in tooling like Hibernate or MyBatis, not directly by your code. In particular, container hosted data sources can participate in JTA transactions, which can be handy when using multiple data sources. You usually install the JDBC driver in the container / app server for this approach.

Confused yet? Welcome to the wonderful world of Java.

### Getting started

To make a quick start, pick a container/app server. Use its provided JPA implementation. For data sources, use whatever's easiest for that configuration - bundled JDBC driver and app managed connection pool, or container-provided DataSource. Pick a tutorial that applies to your situation and follow it. Learn the rest later.

If you're still stuck, start with one of these:

- Glassfish + EclipseLink
- JBoss AS 7 + Hibernate
- Tomcat with OpenJPA

(When someone faffs on about the magic of cross container portability, ask them if they've got a real world app with significant amounts of data and workload that deploys to multiple containers without tweaks - and whether that app actually uses the portable Java EE standards like JPA, JPA 2 Criteria, etc.)

Comment: I should use JsonReader to retrieve data from the postgresql database.I am new to all of these things.Can you please explain how should I use JsonReader to get data from postgresql database?

Answer (score 0):

Download the JAR file from the [json-simple site](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) and use it in your app. There are examples on how to use the library on the site. Putting properties to the JSONObject class 
resembles the way HashMap works. The last thing you need to do after you have completed building a JSONReader compliant JSON is to use the PrintWriter class from the HttpServletResponse class to produce a JSON response like so:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(jsonobject);
```

System.out.print() will not work because the output will just go to standard output (console).